# Tracking how long it takes a user to submit a node edit form?

Tags: 8, forms

For a quiz node, I want to track how long it takes a user to submit a node form (the time from Drupal generating the form until the time that the user presses submit), and I want to store this duration in a field on my node.

**Use case**

Each node of content type **Quiz** is a 10 question quiz.  I want to track the time that users spend filling out the node in order to track their improvement in speed over time.

I do NOT want to track the time spent on the website in general; for that, I already use Google Analytics with scroll tracking, and there is also the [Time Spent](https://www.drupal.org/project/time_spent) module.

**What I tried**

On my node, I added an *Integer* field, **Duration**.  My thought was that I could calculate the interval from the timestamp when the form was generated until the time the node was saved by adding code in `hook_node_presave()`:

```
  $original_time = ??? // How do I get the time when the node form was generated? 
  $current_time = \Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime();
  $duration = $current_time - $original_time;
```

Where I'm stuck is I don't know how to get the time when the node form was created.

I tried to add a *Datetime* field to my node with a **Default date** of *Current date*, but the current date is not set until the node is saved, so that doesn't work.

So, how can I track the time from generating a node edit form until the time the user presses submit?

Comment: I would take a look at the Honeypot module which also tracks the time between showing a form and submitting it. It uses this as part of a strategy to detect spam bots. Check out `honeypot_add_form_protection()` and `_honeypot_time_restriction_validate()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
/*
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_node_quiz_edit_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_duration']['widget'][0]['value']['#type'] = 'hidden'; // hide field
  $form['field_duration']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = time(); // set default value to start time
  array_unshift($form['actions']['submit']['#submit'], 'mymodule_calc_duration'); // adds a custom submit that runs before the default node submit
}

function mymodule_calc_duration(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $start_time = $form_state->getValue('field_duration')[0]['value']; // get default value
  $duration = time() - $start_time; // calculate duration
  $duration_value = [
    ['value' => $duration],
  ];
  $form_state->setValue('field_duration', $duration_value); // set duration value
}
```

Comment: Simple and clean solution

Comment: Updated the answer, its actually better practice to put in in a submit function. Doing it in validation would still be ok if the only validation is just the "required field" aspect, which in D8 it happens on the browser via jQuery. But if there is other validation that does not occur on the browser, it would cause the time to reset. So doing it on submit is full proof.

Answer (score 1):

Based on NoSssweat's code, I was able to get a working solution for my site.

Note the use of `\Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime()` instead of `time()`; this is necessary if you are using something like the [Datetime Testing](https://www.drupal.org/project/datetime_testing) module to change the time for behat tests, because in that case you have to rely on Drupal's time, not the server time.

```
/*
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_node_quiz_edit_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_duration']['widget'][0]['field_duration']['#type'] = 'hidden'; // hide field
  $form['field_duration']['widget'][0]['field_duration']['#default_value'] = \Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime(); // set default value to start time
  $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_calc_duration'; // adds custom validation that runs after all other validation passes
}

function mymodule_calc_duration(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $start_time = $form_state->getValue('field_duration'); // get default value
  $duration = \Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime() - $start_time; // calculate duration
  $duration_value = [
    ['value' => $duration],
  ];
  $form_state->setValue('field_duration', $duration_value); // set duration value
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. create a field in your form and in `Hook_form_alter` and hide it

```
  if ($form_id == 'form_id') {
      $form['field_view_node_start']['#access'] = FALSE;
      $form['field_view_node_start']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = time();
  }
```

2. at hook_entity_presave get time between field_view_node_start and field_view_node_end

```
function hook_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
      $entity->set("field_view_node_end",time());
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work; the values of `time()` in `hook_form_alter()` and `hook_entity_presave()` are the same.

Comment: Is it possible, that it's not the value of `time()`, which is the same, but that you assign a variable in `hook_form_alter()`, the value of which is overridden again when you submit the form? Or did you test it exactly in the suggested way?

Comment: Yes, the Form API does not cache the first build of a form. You could use a [hidden](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Hidden.php/class/Hidden/9.0.x) form element which value you then find in the submitted data in a submit handler. Or use a session value to store the start time on the server if you want to make sure the browser doesn't manipulate the submitted data.